# Equivalent Selenium Webdriver call to replace Protractor call

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

We are migrating from Protractor to using SeleniumWebdriver for Node.js:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

Using Protractor for AngularJS, we can do:

```
element.all(by.repeater('r in roles')).first().element(by.css('.update-role')).click();
```

I am trying to figure out what an equivalent call might look like using `require('selenium-webdriver')`, anybody have an idea?

Specifically, the `by.repeater()` call, is what I don't know an equivalent for.

Comment: just use css with [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to grab by repeater attribute.  idk what the webdriver syntax would be but `[ng-repeat="r in roles"]` is the gist

Comment: Post some example HTML of the elements that would find?

Answer (score 1):

this is fairly simple. you need to find all the elements, and treat them as similar elements.

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-repeat="r in roles"]')).then(function(eachRepeat){
    for(var i=0;i<eachRepeat.length; i++){
        // do something else with the repeat. where eachRepeat[0] is the first element
       console.log(eachRepeat[i]);
    }
});
```

you could also add a condition for the element number. or element's text.

```
element.all(by.css('[ng-repeat="r in roles"]')).getText().then(function(eachRepeat){
        for(var i=0;i<eachRepeat.length; i++){
           console.log(eachRepeat[i]);
           if(eachRepeat[i] === 'someSpecificText'){
                eachRepeat[i].click();
           }else{
           console.log('error');
           }
        }
    });
```

Let me know if you have any questions on this.